# upgrade angular from 12 to 13 added can not use import.meta outside a module

Tags: angular, webpack

I upgrade my angular project from 12 to 13 but getting error
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module.I wanted to use both require and import in my project
I tried using "type"=module but getting error in webpack.config.js file

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Comment: The value of the module field in your tsconfig.json controls whether you can use import.meta.  I don't know if you can mix and match require and import.  What is your use case for this?

Comment: ya I have resolved this issue

Answer (score 16):

The issue might be related to webpack.config setting the publicPath to 'auto'. You might have to set the relative path.
Other option to fix this issue will be to set the scriptType property to 'text/javascript' in the webpack.config as follows:

```
 module.exports = {
        output: {
            uniqueName: "MyProj",
            publicPath: "auto",
            scriptType: 'text/javascript'
        }
```

This option will not migrate microfrontend and it bring back the behavior of Angular 12.

A more detailed article on microfrontend upgrade can be found here:
https://github.com/angular-architects/module-federation-plugin/blob/main/migration-guide.md

Answer (score 2):

```
const { shareAll, withModuleFederationPlugin } = require('@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack');

const webpackConfig = withModuleFederationPlugin({...})

module.exports = {
  ...webpackConfig,
  output: {
    ...webpackConfig.output,
    scriptType: 'text/javascript'
  }
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: After the initialization of `module.exports` using `withModuleFederationPlugin`, use this line to set the scriptType to text/javascript:
`module.exports.output.scriptType = "text/javascript"`