# Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module - Nx Monorepo

Tags: angular, monorepo, nrwl

I created an angular nx monorepo and created two applications. When I start either of them I get the following error:

[image: error-message]

I already saw some stackoverflow posts were the answers suggested to just add "type": "module" to package.json. But since it is a monorepo only one package.json is used for all the apps.

microfrontend:

[image]

Comment: like to know this, too

Comment: @LukeChi, I found out, that this can be ignored and is a known error, which cannot be fixed, but also has no unintentional side effects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For posterity on the newer versions of [NX](https://nx.dev/recipes/module-federation/dynamic-module-federation-with-angular):

> When serving module federation apps in dev mode locally, there'll be an error output to the console, import.meta cannot be used outside of a module, and the script that is coming from is styles.js. It's a known error output, but it doesn't actually cause any breakages from as far as our testing has shown. It's because Angular compiler attaches the styles.js file to the index.html in a script tag with defer.
>
> It needs to be attached with type=module, but Angular can't make that
> change because it breaks HMR. They also provide no way of hooking into
> that process for us to patch it ourselves.
>
> The good news is that the error doesn't propagate to production,
> because styles are compiled to a CSS file , so there's no erroneous JS
> to log an error.
>
> It's worth stressing that there's been no actual errors or breakages
> noted from our tests.

Answer (score 8):

This has been asked already, and the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70523679/13140310)

You just need to adjust your

```
module.exports = {
    output: {
        uniqueName: "MyProj",
        publicPath: "auto",
        scriptType: 'text/javascript'
    }
```

to include `scriptType: 'text/javascript'`

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this is because Angular loads css like this:

```
<script src="something.css">
```

whereas this should actually be

```
<script src="something.css" type="module">
```

They apparently do this on purpose to bypass some issues. But we don't have to worry about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this;

```js
// Replace "styles.js" with your own javascript file.

const importMetaUrl = "undefined" == typeof document ? require("url").pathToFileURL(__filename).href : document.currentScript && document.currentScript.src || new URL("styles.js", document.baseURI).href;

console.log(importMetaUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was recently dealing with this issue and experienced a few things:

adding output: {
publicPath:"auto",
scriptType:"text/javascript"
}

did in fact make the import.meta error go away but then I started facing another issue relating to chunk loading:

"Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html""

changing scriptType: 'module' resolved it as well. If anyone faces the same issues after fixing the import.meta issue.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputscripttype