# Angular Module federation with two different remote apps

Tags: angular, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

I have 2 remote apps and a host.

mfe1(remote) have 2 routes products and services
mfe2(remote) have 2 routes cart and settings

I want to load them in a shell app.

added

```
ng add @angular-architects/module-federation
```

Throwing error

```
TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module
```

Do I need to add anything to get rid of this error ?

here is the webpack config's

MFE1 : https://gitlab.com/nchakilam/mfe1/-/blob/main/webpack.config.js?ref_type=heads

MFE2:  https://gitlab.com/nchakilam/mfe2/-/blob/main/webpack.config.js?ref_type=heads

Shell: https://gitlab.com/nchakilam/shell/-/blob/main/webpack.config.js?ref_type=heads

```
Shell: https://gitlab.com/nchakilam/shell
MFE1: https://gitlab.com/nchakilam/mfe1
MFE2: https://gitlab.com/nchakilam/mfe2
```

tried dynamic loading

```
{
  path: 'products',
    loadChildren:() => loadRemoteModule({
      type: 'module',
      remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:4201/remoteEntry.ts',
      exposedModule: './Module'
    }).then(m=>m.MfeOneModule)
  },

  {
    path: 'cart',
    loadChildren:() => loadRemoteModule({
      type: 'module',
      remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:4202/remoteEntry.ts',
      exposedModule: './Module'
    }).then(m=>m.MfeTwoModule)
  },
```

throws error

```
 TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module
```

Comment: it seems someone else had that issue already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72221157/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-meta-outside-a-module-nx-monorepo)